# How to query facebook graph and parse returned json in codeigniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, curl

I am trying to pull my friends list using the following url

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$facebookid."/fql?
        q=SELECT uid,name FROM user WHERE uid IN(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) ORDER BY name
        &access_token=".$accesstoken."
        &limit=10000&offset=0";
        //echo $url."<br/>";
$list = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
```

When i try to print the array, it always return empty.. If the same url is tested all my friends list is listed in a json

How to parse this... I am using codeigniter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably have to encode the query by [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode) as follows:

```php
$query = "SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) ORDER BY name";

$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/$facebookid/fql?q=" . urlencode($query) .
       "&access_token=$accesstoken&limit=10000&offset=0";

$list = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
```

Either to use [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) or [`curl`](http://php.net/curl):

```php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

if(! $result = curl_exec($ch)) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
} else {
    $res = json_decode($result, true);
}

curl_close($ch);
var_dump($res);
```

Comment: It isn't working, still returns an empty.. Anything to work with cURL ?

Comment: @Ramaraju.d Make sure the query is correct. You can echo `$url` out and   enter that directly into your address bar to check the result.

Comment: Yes, i did it.. It works fine.. but the same doesn't fetch in an array. from the file_get_contents i am not getting the result

Comment: @Ramaraju.d Updated the answer, used curl to get the result.